# How to parse JSON in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have the following JSON string :

```
{"configuration":{"dates":["a","b","c"],"areas":["0","1"]}}
```

I'm trying to get the values of the dates (a, b, c) and the areas (0, 1);

I tried to get the dates as follows :

```
select * from xmltable ('/json/row' passing apex_json.to_xmltype(JsonText) 
columns 
    dates varchar2(15) path '/row/configuration/dates');
```

But the query is not returning anything.

How can I parse this JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parse JSON data with an XML parser; instead use a JSON parser such as `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT a.area,
       d.dt
FROM   (
         select area,
                dates,
                ROWNUM AS rn -- Force the sub-query to be materialized.
         from   table_name t
                CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
                  t.JsonText,
                  '$.configuration'
                  COLUMNS (
                    dates CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.dates',
                    NESTED PATH '$.areas[*]' COLUMNS (
                      area VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$'
                    )
                  )
                )
       ) a
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         a.dates,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           dt VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$'
         )
       ) d;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( JsonText CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name (jsontext)
VALUES ('{"configuration":{"dates":["a","b","c"],"areas":["0","1"]}}');
```

Outputs:

| AREA | DT |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 0 | b |
| 0 | c |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |

---

If you just want to extract the JSON arrays then:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.jsontext,
         '$.configuration'
         COLUMNS (
           dates CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.dates',
           areas CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.areas'
         )
       ) j
```

Which outputs:

| DATES | AREAS |
| --- | --- |
| ["a","b","c"] | ["0","1"] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tj3bzTcd)